# Why does isalpha return only 1 or 0?

Tags: c

When I run isalpha in vscode with c17-standard (or any other) it always returns only 1 or 0. Yet when i run it on another system it returns also bigger numbers than 1. How does isalpha work? Where can I see which implementation do I have? What causes this difference in behaviour on my system?

I realise this question might be very weird or irrelevant but I tried to search for an answer yet couldn't find one.

Comment: There is neither difference in the behavior. 1 is a non-zero value.

Comment: I know that it works correctly according to documentation. But when I run it on another systems it returns bigger numbers than 1. I'm wondering why it behaves differently on my system.

Comment: What return value did you expect? According to the documentation it would be OK to return any other non-zero value instead of 1, e.g. 127 or -5 or even different values for all alphabetic characters. You can only rely on the fact that it is either non-zero or zero.

Comment: @Arcod It only means that implementations are allowed to return any non-zero value.

Comment: Ideally, `isalpha` should return a Boolean value. But since Boolean values did no exist in C language by the time `isalpha` was introduced, an `int` acting as a Boolean is used: either 0 (false) or something else (true).

Comment: I wouldn't wonder too much about the exact value. Just like `strcmp` can return less-than-zero or greater-than-zero, the exact value isn't important just the relationship to zero.

Comment: isalpha returns a boolean. 
In C, a boolean is 0 for FALSE and anything else for TRUE.
This loose definition allows several optimisations, but doesn't mean your answer will be anything other than 1, as most boolean checks operators only return 0 or 1.

Comment: The returned value *can* be other than `1` and so you should check for `== 0` or `!= 0`

Comment: This actually is an interesting question. A common implementation of the `<ctype.h>` macros is to have a table of words, `T[c]`, indexed by a character or `EOF` in `c`, with each bit in `T[c]` corresponding to some class, so the bit is set if `c` is a member of that class. Then the macros `isalpha` and such are implemented principally as `T[c] & MaskForThisClass`. In this implementation, the “true” values returned are naturally different from 1 (except for the one class mapped to bit 1). So it is interesting why an implementation would go to the trouble of reducing the result to 1.

Comment: One reason I see is to support code written with the incorrect assumption that `isalpha` and other routines return only 0 or 1.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From the C standard:

> 7.4.1  Character classification  functions
>
> 1. The  functions  in  this  subclause  return  **nonzero  (true)**  if  and  only  if  the  value  of  the argument conforms to that in
>    the description of the function.

When you implement the function from this class you do not have to return `1` or `0`. You are free to return any nonzero value not only `1`

Answer (score 0):

Here is my isalpha() implementation found in headerfile ctype.h :

```
__DARWIN_CTYPE_TOP_inline int
isalpha(int _c)
{
return (__istype(_c, _CTYPE_A));
}
```

Here is the __istype() function used in it :

```
__istype(__darwin_ct_rune_t _c, unsigned long _f)
{
#ifdef USE_ASCII
    return !!(__maskrune(_c, _f));
#else /* USE_ASCII */
    return (isascii(_c) ? !!(_DefaultRuneLocale.__runetype[_c] & _f)
        : !!__maskrune(_c, _f));
#endif /* USE_ASCII */
}
```

From what I can understand double negation '!!' is used to convert any non 1 integer to 1 except 0 which stays 0. This would explain why my isalpha returns only 0 or 1.